Is it possible to access a field defined by an extension from another extension?
So here's an overview of our enviroment: Extension A made by Developer A, Extension B made by Developer B, and Extension C made by me.
I need to access a field in the Item Ledger Entry table defined by another extension. I am attempting to create a new extension that can read some data this extension added to the table. I am able to access a custom field defined by Developer A (as well as download the source code) but it seems like the other field (Extension B) I need is privated or something. I am also unable to view the source code of Extension B. Is there a way I can access the field? Is this a permission issue?
I am doing some work on a legacy BC App and would love any help you guys can give!

It could be that the developer B sets the 'resourceExposurePolicy' of that extension to not allowDownloadingSource and not includeSourceInSymbolFile. So you can't download source code or view code inside symbol.
And fields indeed have access property that devs can set, so it is best to contact the developer about this issue.

You can access the field by Extension B by using a FieldRef. The resulting code will not be very readable, because you will use the field's Id.
There are no additional permissions neccessary (you still need permission to access the table "Item Ledger Entry").
Example:
myRecordRef.GetTable(ItemLedgerEntry);
myFieldRef := myRecordRef.Field( fieldId );
ValueFromExtensionB := myFieldRef.Value();


I've done this via dependancies defined in the app.json for my extension.
Using this, I was able to reach tables / fields created by the foreign extension.
I dont think access to source is required for this to work, haven't specifically tested for it.
in app.json:
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "Example",
      "publisher": "Example Publisher",
      "version": "1.2.3.4",
      "id": "11111-222222-33333"
    }

Then download symbols again and the field should be available.
Sidenote:
If you need to determine what extension handles a feild, use the BC Page Inspection and find your field, it'll show the ExtensionSource. Go to Extension Management to get the ID, etc.
